# Given arbitrary $\mathbf{r}(x,y,z)$ and constant $\dot{r}$, can I find $x(t)$, $y(t)$, and $z(t)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose I am walking along an arbitrary path $\mathbf{r}(x,y,z)$ (okay, so I'm allowed to hover, too).

I wish to hover along this path at a constant speed $||\dot{\mathbf{r}}||$.

Given that information, is it possible to find $x(t)$, $y(t)$, and $z(t)$?

Comment: How come the position vector $\mathbf{r}$ is defined as a scalar here?

Comment: because i am stupid. $||\mathbf{r}||=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. i know better.

Comment: shouldn't $\mathbf r$ be a function of $t$, not $x,y,z$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the differential of arclength along the path by $ds=\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2+dz^2}$.  Then you can get the arclength from one end by integrating up.  Divide by your desired speed and you get the time to be at each point.

Comment: When you say "integrating up" I assume you mean [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#Finding_arc_lengths_by_integrating), right, not taking a path integral?

Comment: @DangKhoa:  that is correct.

Comment: From that Wiki page, I would extend the formula to include $dz$ as follows: $ds=\sqrt{1+(dy/dx)^2+(dz/dx)^2}dx$? If that's the case, then there's no loss of generality and I could potentially (as a check) integrate against $x$, $y$, or $z$ (using the appropriate bounds), right?

Comment: @DangKhoa:  you are coorect.  You can integrate over whichever is convenient and if you do more than one you should get the same answer each time.